# How to detect which astype header in pandas is failing conversion?

Tags: pandas

For some reason, my big dataframe is failing astype conversion and I get an error message as follows:
`could not convert string to float: 'False'.`

Now since I have 100 columns, I want to detect in which column the astype conversion is failing, so looking at traceback:

```
result = result.astype(pdSchema)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5859, in astype
   col.astype(dtype=dtype[col_name], copy=copy, errors=errors)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5874, in astype
   new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 631, in astype
   return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 427, in apply
   applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 673, in astype
   values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
 File "C:\Users\spidey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1097, in astype_nansafe
   return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'False'
```

I can determine the value is 'False' but I can't determnie in which column it's failing and since my multiple columns have similar value, In order to handle this exception, I want to know the column name where it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `pdSchema` is dict, so you can test it by:

```
for k, v in pdSchema.items():
    try:
        result[k].astype(v)
    except ValueError:
        print (f'Column {k} failed for converting to {v}')
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is so simple yet so innovative. Never thought it this way, thank you so much buddy.